# Java Calculate Max Steps of Stairs and skip stair

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I recently got an interview for an intern position and one of the questions was similar to this:

> **Input**: n for number of actions, k for a stair that you could not step
>   on
>
> **Question**: Jack has n amount of actions where he wants to reach the
>   maximum number of steps but cannot step on the kth stair. For each
>   action, Jack can either stay at his current step or jump i steps if he
>   is on his ith action and this keeps going until he finished his nth
>   action.
>
> **Output**: The maximum stair he can reach within n actions

It was tested via Hackerrank (with the interviewer there) and I passed only 3 out of 8 test cases with the rest timing out

This was my solution that was coded on the fly and I could not optimize it and was wondering if there was a much more optimized solution:

```
static int maxStep(int n, int k) {
    int result = 0;
    if (n == 0) {
        return result;
    } 
    return maxStepHelper(n,0, k, result);
}

static int maxStepHelper(int n,int i,int k,int result) {
    // At n+1 steps, previous steps' results are recorded and this is mainly used to stop and show previous results
    if (i == n+1) {
        return result;
    }
    int nextStep = i + result;
    if (nextStep == k) {
       return maxStepHelper(n,i+1,k,result);
    } 
    return Math.max(maxStepHelper(n,i+1,k,result),maxStepHelper(n,i+1,k,result+i));
}
```

Note that I used a recursive approach which might not have helped

Comment: Jump `i` steps from step `i`, or jump *up to* `i` steps? And which step do you start on (presumably not zero).

Comment: You seem to only be moving `i+1`. Instructions say you can move up `i` steps for any stair `i`

Comment: Sorry guess I wasn't clear: jump i steps from step i and you start at 0

Comment: If you can take `i` steps up from step `i`, and you start at `i==0`, how can you ever take any steps?

Comment: Oh I meant ith action, let me change that, sorry it's been some time

Comment: I think this should migrate to codereview : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no need for recursion or dynamic programming here; it's just a bit of maths.

If you take `i` steps on each turn, you will take `(n * (n+1)) / 2` steps. You will land on the `k`-th step if `k` is an integer solution to the equation:

```
k = (n * (n+1)) / 2
```

Rearranging:

```
0 = n^2 + n - 2*k
```

which is a quadratic equation in `n`:

```
n = (-1 +/- sqrt(1 + 4*1*2*k)) / 2
```

which only has an integer solution if `sqrt(1 + 8*k)` is an odd integer.

So:

- If `sqrt(1 + 8*k)` is an odd integer, you would land on the `k`-th step. So, just don't take a step on the first action, and you'll miss `k` by 1. The maximum number of steps is `(n * (n+1)) / 2 - 1`.

  It's the first action that you want to miss out, because 1 is the smallest number of steps you can be short by. If you miss out the second action, you will be 2 steps shorter than the maximum etc.
- Otherwise, just take `i` steps on each action, and the maximum number of steps is `(n * (n+1)) / 2`

Comment: that's the answer I thought about, just one problem, how to check if `sqrt(1+8k)` is integer ? this problem can be solved easily for small numbers but for very large numbers incomplete floating-point math becomes an issue

Comment: If you're particularly concerned about big numbers, you can always just sum `1+2+3+...+n` in a for loop, and decrement the sum by 1 if it ever equals `k`. Or use [some well-known algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots) to calculate the integer square root.